# How do I create a new folder in Google Drive using the API via ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, google-drive-api

I've been trying to follow the documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert and https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder.  However, I'm not clear on exactly what information I need to be passing during the http call.  When I run the following code it simply creates a file that Drive says it doesn't know how to open:

```
    <cfhttp method="post" url="https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files">
        <cfhttpparam type="header"  name="Content-Type"     value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="key"              value="#myKey#">
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="access_token"     value="#myAccessToken#">
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="corpus"           value="DEFAULT">
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="uploadType"       value="multipart">
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="Content-Type"     value="application/json; charset=UTF-8 {""title"": ""Test 001"", ""parents"": [{""id"":""#validParentID#""}]}">
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="Content-Type"     value="application/vnd.google-apps.folder">
    </cfhttp>
```

This code was derived from my call that successfully creates an empty file (although I've not yet gotten the title to work).

**UPDATE**

I updated the code per Jedihomer Townend's suggestion:

```
    <cfhttp method="post" url="https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files">
        <cfhttpparam type="header"  name="Content-Type"     value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="key"              value="#myKey#">
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="access_token"     value="#myAccessToken#">
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="corpus"           value="DEFAULT">
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="uploadType"       value="multipart">
        <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="Content-Type"     value="application/json; charset=UTF-8 {""mimeType"": ""application/vnd.google-apps.folder"" ""title"": ""Test 001"", ""parents"": [{""id"":""#validParentID#""}]}">
    </cfhttp>
```

This had the same result as my original code.

**BOUNTY**

I'm starting a bounty on this now.  In addition to resolving this particular problem, I'd also appreciate insights on how to apply Google's documentation to direct http calls.  Despite REST being a technology designed around http requests, Google's docs (pun intended) seem to cover only an OOP approach to using it.

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder it would look like you are missing "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" from the JSON packet.  What happens if you add that to the application/json cfhttpparam line?

Comment: @JedihomerTownend Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried modifying the code as suggested, but with the same result.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is: Why are you using `cfhttpparam type="URL"` with a POST? The correct type would be `FORMFIELD` to add it as key-value-pair to the body of the request while `type="URL"` will add it to the query string of the endpoint.

Comment: Would a PHP way also suit your needs?

Comment: @AlexanderKwaschny Good question.  It's because this is the only way it (sort of) works.  If I change the cfhttpparams to formfields Google responds with a "Login Required", and doesn't seem to recognize that anything was passed along.  If I change it to a get operation I receive a "405 Method Not Allowed"; I'm not sure why.  I've gone through a lot of permutations of this code that made more sense, but this is the closest I've got to proper functionality.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the offer.  I'd be willing to take a look, but I don't know PHP; I've come across a few PHP tutorials in the past but they unfortunately haven't been much help.

Comment: can you try passing access token in authorization header like Bearer <access token>

Comment: @dungeonHunter Thanks for the suggestion.  How would I do that in ColdFusion?